# How to expand a function into a power series with negative powers?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

Is there any way to expand this expression

```
a+b(1-Exp[-T/(b c)]/(z-Exp[-T/ (b c)])
```

(where `a`, `b`, `c`, and `T` are constants) as a series in *negative* powers of $z$?  The result should be in the form

```
a0 + a1 z^(-1) + a2 z^(-2) + a3 z^(-3) + ... + an z^(-n)
```

I tried solutions like `Series[a + b (1 - k/(z - k)), {z, 0, -5}]` but this did not work.

Thank you.

Comment: An expansion around zero `Series[a + b (1 - k/(z - k)), {z, 0, 5}]` gives $(a+2 b)+\frac{b z}{k}+\frac{b z^2}{k^2}+\frac{b z^3}{k^3}+\frac{b z^4}{k^4}+\frac{b
   z^5}{k^5}+O\left(z^6\right)$

Comment: @image_doctor thank you for the answer. but i want a serie with negative power.
Series[a + b (1 - k/(z - k)), {z, 0, -5}] don't work

Comment: I was going to suggest expanding at infinity, then noticed @whuber said it better.

Answer (score 17):

You want first to fix any typographical errors (such as the unbalanced parentheses) and it's also wise to avoid symbol names beginning with capital letters.  Then, to obtain a series expansion in powers of $1/z$, expand the expression around *infinity*, not zero:

```
Series[a + b (1 - Exp[-t/(b c)]/(z - Exp[-t/(b c)])) , {z, Infinity, 5}]
```

> $(a+b)-\frac{b e^{-\frac{t}{b c}}}{z}-\frac{b e^{-\frac{2 t}{b c}}}{z^2}-\frac{b e^{-\frac{3 t}{b c}}}{z^3}-\frac{b e^{-\frac{4 t}{b c}}}{z^4}-\frac{b e^{-\frac{5 t}{b c}}}{z^5}+O\left[\frac{1}{z}\right]^6$

To confirm this, we could also replace $z$ by $1/z$, expand the series in *non-negative* powers of $z$, and then substitute $1/z$ back for $z$ once more:

```
Series[a + b (1 - Exp[-t/(b c)]/(z - Exp[-t/(b c)])) /. z -> (1/z), {z, 0, 5}] /. z -> 1/z
```

> $(a+b)-\frac{b e^{-\frac{t}{b c}}}{z}-b e^{-\frac{2 t}{b c}} \left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^2-b e^{-\frac{3 t}{b c}} \left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^3-b e^{-\frac{4 t}{b c}} \left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^4-b e^{-\frac{5 t}{b c}} \left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^5+O\left[\frac{1}{z}\right]^6$

The two results are clearly equivalent expressions of the same series.  If the terminal `O[]` term is undesirable, remove it by applying `Normal` to the output.

Comment: Thank you whuber, thats what am looking for :-)